# Usage of " at the expense of"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, ambiguity

I am reading the poem *The Latest Decalogue* by Arthur Hugh Clough.
I can't understand the meaning of this line:

> Thou shalt have one God only; who / Would be at the expense of two?

Is he saying that to have one God in Christianity means that you have to have three Gods at the same time?

Comment: The source I found quotes as follows: Thou shalt have one God only; who 
    Would tax himself to worship two?

Comment: No, he is saying (sarcastically) 'Why go to the trouble of worshipping more than one god when you need only worship one?'

Comment: @KateBunting   It is a satire about "Ten Commands". Does it make sense this way?

Comment: Yes, I know - that's why I pointed out that the tone was sarcastic.

Comment: With the comments by @KateBunting & Xanne ( & other online resources ) , we can conclude that the Poet is **rhetorically asking** why rich folks should have 2 or more gods & pay the "expensive" "tax" or "offering" to all those , when the same rich folks can get away with paying a small amount to one god. Poet then says that rich folks can see god in the currency. Hence , the correct way to consider the phrase "who would be at the expense of two?" is that it is a **rhetorical question** with the **rhetorical answer** "no body!" which is mocking those rick folks.

Comment: The @Xanne comments are clear and correct and deserve to be an answer rather than mere comment.

Comment: Personally, I'd have phrased it *Who would **go to** the expense of [metaphorically "paying the price / incurring the overhead" for something you don't need]?* Same syntax as *Who would **go to the trouble of** [doing something unnecessary]?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can only guess as to what exactly was meant by Arthur Hugh Clough (1819–1861). "The Latest Decalogue" by Arthur Hugh Clough is obviously a satire in which he criticises the Victorians, specifically the contrast between the impression they gave of themselves, and their true morality as per this report ([website: 123helpme.com](https://www.123helpme.com/essay/The-Latest-Decalogue-by-Arthur-Hugh-Clough-239495)).

In it he advises the Victorians to have only one God (God of currency or money God), and also advises not to be bound to do two God's ("money God" and "God of ten commandments") bidding (aka serve). "Would be at the expense of two" can be expanded to "Would be placed at the expense of two (Gods)" or rephrased as "Would be at the disposal of two Gods". Arthur Hugh Clough advises that it is better to serve one God (the money God), follow the new ten commandments (The Latest Decalogue) and make a show of following the original ten commandments.

In the whole of the poem, Arthur Hugh Clough is advising/rebuking/chastising Victorians to make a show of abiding by the "ten commandments", and in their inner core abide by the "The Latest Decalogue". It's wordplay by a poet.